# GraphQL Subscription gets closed with 1000 Normal Closure immediately after opening (SpringBoot)

Tags: java, spring-boot, graphql, graphql-java, graphql-subscriptions

I'm having trouble with using GraphQL Subscriptions in SpringBoot
Whenever I run my application and run a subscription query on Postman, it works for the first time after starting.

[Immediately after starting the Application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OzlwU.png)

The data is also received if the trigger is pulled, so that is working.

But once I try to run the subscription again, I get this:
[Subsequent subscription call](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ibcVp.png)

For reference, here's the code: [GitHub](https://github.com/chethan-hebbar/graphql_springboot)

Please help, been stuck with this issue for some time.

Comment: Hi there! Could you post relevant code snippets inside of your question, as well as inline images so we don't have to follow links everywhere? It helps us help you!

Comment: I was 100% sure the issue would be the implicit auto cancellation in `onBackpressureBuffer`, but looking at your code I see you avoided that trap! Kudos! But I unfortunately don't have another idea on what could be wrong :/

Comment: Hey guys, thanks for the response, you are right, its an issue with onBackpressureBuffer.
Adding two params, (Queues.SMALL_BUFFER_SIZE, false) fixes this issue of auto-closure.
Would be great if someone can explain what exactly is happening there...